# Как на C выделить целую часть числа и как округлить число до ближайшего целого?

Tags: c

Как на C можно выделить целую часть числа. И как можно округлить число до ближайшего целого?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Хотите целую часть? - Сделайте явное приведение типов:

```
double a = 1.11 
b = (int) a
```

Хотите узнать дробную часть? Разделите число на него же, но после приведения типов и проанализируйте остаток от деления через if-else блок: сможете своим способом округление сделать.

Или не забывайте про библиотеку math. C++ style:

```
double d = 2.71;
double x, y;    
y = std::modf(d, &x); // целая часть запишется в x, дробная - в y
```

Comment: А округление (int)(a+0.5);

Comment: Остроумно. Сами придумали или вычитали где-то?

Comment: В math.h есть функции trunc и round (в разных вариациях типов аргумента и значения)

Comment: только надо иметь ввиду что trunk и round возвращает тип float.

Comment: @aknew 

1. Они возвращают тип double

2. Это не проблема

3. Есть функция lround, которая возвращает тип long, и llround - long long

Comment: Про дабл, честно говоря, забыл, а что не проблема это ясно, но просто надо об этом помнить

Comment: Ну скажем, у truncf и аргумент, и результат имеют тип float, а у truncl -- long double :)

Comment: Как в том еврейском анекдоте; "И ты, Мойша, тоже прав".

Comment: >А округление (int)(a+0.5);

 Гениально и просто. Теперь буду использовать у себя, а то я там if'ы нагромоздил. Наверное быстрее будет работать, чем мои if'ы, хотя там где я их использовал это было некритично.

Comment: Это решение правильно лишь отчасти. Число с плавающей точкой имеет больший диапазон значений, чем int, поэтому для значений больших ёмкости int  получится переполнение и не правильный ответ. Существует ли математический способ найти целую часть не ограничиваясь размером int?